# Using Font Awesome 5 with Bootstrap 3 Collapse Component -- change arrow icon on collapse?

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-4, font-awesome

I'm trying to use Font Awesome 5 with Bootstrap 4 for an accordion/collapse section in my VUEJS SPA.

How can I get the Font Awesome arrow icon to point DOWN when a collapseable element is clicked?

[image]

[Paste bin link](https://pastebin.com/1P6BPK8R)

```
<template>
    <div>
      <div class='card-header' data-toggle='collapse' href='#collapseZero'>
          <a class='card-title'>Heading Title One</a>
          <font-awesome-icon :icon='faAngleUp' class='float-right'></font-awesome-icon>
              </div>
                  <div id='collapseOne' class='card-body collapse' data-parent='#accordion'>
                      Content blah
                  </div>
      </div>
</template>

<script>
import { faAngleUp, faAngleDown } from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

export default {
  name: 'MyName'
  computed: {
    faAngleUp() {
      return faAngleUp;
    }
    faAngleDOwn() {
        return faAngleDown;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you're looking for pure CSS approach or not, but just in case you do:

#### HTML

Simple accordin example. Pay attention the `.collapsed` class and `<i class="fas"></i>` on each `card-header`. You can change the content of the icon to display either arrow up or down based on whether `card-header` has the `.collapsed` class or not.

```html
<div class="accordin">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" 
          data-target="#collapse-card-1">
            Card 1
            <span class="float-right">
                <i class="fas"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-card-1" class="collapse" data-parent=".accordin">
            <div class="card-body">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" 
          data-target="#collapse-card-2">
            Card 2
            <span class="float-right">
                <i class="fas"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-card-2" class="collapse" data-parent=".accordin">
            <div class="card-body">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" 
          data-target="#collapse-card-3">
            Card 3
            <span class="float-right">
                <i class="fas"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse-card-3" class="collapse" data-parent=".accordin">
            <div class="card-body">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```css
.card-header i.fas:before {
    content: "\f107";    /* angle-down */
}

.card-header.collapsed i.fas:before {
    content: "\f106";    /* angle-up */
}
```

#### Fiddle Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/tgq2j0fh/